# Oracle: Export row with dependencies

Tags: sql, oracle

I`ve got a table 'Students' which has foreign key to tables 'School' and 'Teachers' and ... . I want to export a specific student (row) and a teacher and school and other rows connected with it. How to do it?

Comment: For "exporting" you can use Data Pump?

Comment: Do you mean how to `SELECT` them?

Comment: We'll need more info. Show us your db tables and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Using `expdp` (Data Pump) you can limit the data to be exported with the `QUERY` Parameter ([Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL860)), which is basically a `WHERE`-clause (so you have to use Sub-Selects to join the tables):

Contents of the Parameter(par)-file exp.par:

```
include=TABLE:"IN ('STUDENTS','TEACHERS', 'SCHOOLS')" 
query=STUDENTS:"WHERE student_name=\'STUDENT ONE\'"
query=SCHOOLS:"WHERE school_pk in ( select school_fk from STUDENTS where student_name=\'STUDENT ONE\')"
...
```

and so on...
Then you can start the export like this:

```
$ expdp YOURSCHEMA directory=TEMP dumpfile=data.dmp logfile=expdp.log parfile=exp.par
```